# Setting a Title for Apple Touch Icon for Bookmark on Homescreen

Tags: html, ios, favicon

Is there possibility to define the title of an touch icon on the homescreen of an iOS device?

[image: As you can see below the title of the touch icon has been derived from the URL of my site.]

This is fine for the now but I woule like to have custom title an not a derived one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the Apple docs on touch icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

> On iOS, you can specify a web application title for the launch icon. By default, the  tag is used. To set a different title, add a meta tag to the webpage, as in:
>
> ```
> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="AppTitle">
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I like using this site. https://realfavicongenerator.net/ It gives you the code to add in the head and a zip file with the icons to upload